# MS Access: Link listbox to textbox

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, textbox

I have a textbox and listbox, one is for entering a new topic in a help form while the other looks up those new topics. I would like to be able to present the finished topics in both the textbox and listbox simultaneously to edit or lookup as well write new records in the help form. The listbox provides functionality to view which records there are now.
I find if I put nothing in and I go to a new record the prev/next buttons will stop working, maybe there is a control I need to add to keep it from freezing or to refresh? Normally I press esc to get out of a new record edit and return to others but that does not work as usual.

Or how else may I point to the listbox's current record source?

```
I currently have this code:

Private Sub List35_AfterUpdate()
  DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Help Form_Editor2", acGoTo, Me.List35.ListIndex + 1
    Me.List35 = Me.List35.Column(0, Form.CurrentRecord - 1)
    Dim index As Integer
    index = Form.CurrentRecord - 1
    Me.Text53 = Me.List35.Column(Me.List35.ListIndex + 1, index)
End Sub
```

I keep getting some of the items to read but others are null. I have about 8 items in the source table... what is going wrong? Why would there be nulls?

Another issue after getting this updated. When the code is setup the recordset starts at new when I allow additions and edits on the form. The code displays the list item as it should but the other items will not activate from the requeried listbox item. What might correct this issue?

```
Private Sub List35_AfterUpdate()
    Dim myTitle As String
    With Me.List35
        If .ListIndex > -1 Then
            'Use this one if you are using bound column
            myTitle = .Column(1, Form.CurrentRecord)

            'use this if you want something other than the bound column
            'and you have more than one column in the list (hidden or not)
            'nId = .Column(1, .ListIndex)

           Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM FormsHelpTable WHERE HelpTitle = '" & myTitle & "'"
            Me.Text53.Value = myTitle
        Else
           Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM FormsHelpTable WHERE HelpTitle IS NULL"
            'Me.Text53.Value = "(New)"
        End If

    End With

   Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks for ListIndex. It will be -1 if you don't have anything selected.

```
Private Sub List35_AfterUpdate()
    Dim index As Integer

    With Me.List35
        If .ListIndex > -1 Then
            DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Help Form_Editor2", acGoTo, .ListIndex + 1
            .Value = .Column(0, Form.CurrentRecord - 1)
            index = Form.CurrentRecord - 1
            Me.Text53 = .Column(.ListIndex + 1, index)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

I'm not sure what all your code is trying to do, so I didn't make any other adjustments other than to reduce all references to List35 to a single With statement.

I normally do something like this:

```
Private Sub List35_AfterUpdate()
    Dim nId As Long
    With Me.List35
        If .ListIndex > -1 Then                
            'Use this one if you are using bound column
            nId = .Value 

            'use this if you want something other than the bound column
            'and you have more than one column in the list (hidden or not)
            'nId = .Column(1, .ListIndex)

            Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Id = " & nId
        Else
            Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Id IS NULL"
        End If

    End With

    Me.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It still returns a null in the .column statement with the Me.Text53 line. I am not sure why. On the third item on the listbox it just returns null, the ListIndex is 3 and the index is 3. What do you think?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand how this list array works as others. You say it is -1 if nothing is selected. So it should start on item 0 correct as others do?

Comment: Yes. The Column method returns a value for a zero based column and zero based row.

Comment: I tried the other method. Interesting... the .Value property returned 8 when I chose item 3 (which was actually bound on 2) from the list. Why would the .Value property be 8 which seems random?

Comment: This works! I just refactored the code to show a string instead of the Id number on another field.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but there is one more update on my code. I got the linking from listbox to textbox to work but the recordset is getting confused and wont allow the prev/next buttons to work as if the recordset narrows to the current view which is new id.

Comment: Check the RecordSource property. You may need to reset it to the query that you want. I like to set the property from a listbox and display controls in a subform, but it's unconventional. My code probably fouled you up initially.

Comment: Is there a way to check the RecordSource property in real time?

Comment: I got it to show the records and move from the new to the last record only. I need to save the data from the new record somehow and I think it needs to be done with VBA from the title, maybe save the current value of the textbox to the table souce and then update the listbox and refresh.

Comment: It is the WHERE clause that restricts the movement of the recordset for some reason, but all should qualify. If I remove it the RecordSource is navigable but lacking functionality. So I will work on improving this.